# how to know which apps will be started automatically when i boot android device?

Tags: android, linux, sqlite, autostart, geektool

there are lots of apps which will be started even i don't want them to start once i power on my android device.

so is there any method which can find all the apps that will be started automatically once i boot my android device?   i don't meant to use autostarts app to find these apps, since it is naive:(

i would use cat , less , more, and find related command to find these apps which will be started automatically, but how?

which configure file i should read?  or is such configuration stored in .sqlite database?
seems i cannot find the configuration in /etc/init.d on android(android is based on linux) device, but i can find autostart info in this directory when i am using linux:(

so by the way can i install sqlite commnad line to my android device? is there any already build sqlite command that i could adb push to my device?

Comment: I think this question must be made at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: lol,then help me to move this question to android stackexchange, plz:)

Answer (score 3):

Android is about intents. you'll have to query the intent resolver for applications that answer to the boot intent.

Also, sqlite3 is already on your device.

Comment: i mean sqlite command, can i run sqlite command once i connect to adb shell?